# Java cache database tables and columns

Tags: java, database, caching

I have one quick question. I'm writing desktop application for generating reports from database and I want to get all tables and columns from database (no results of select queries only tables and columns) to put it in list, where user can select it and use to build own queries. I had written my own code to do this, but it is slow. If you see SQuirreL SQL Client you will know what I means. I know that are some libraries for do this but they are big.

I use `SELECT` query to get all table names, and then use `SELECT` query to get columns from that table name.

My code:

```
public List<String> getTables() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM sys.Tables");
        while (rs.next()) {
            tables.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, stmt, rs);
    }
    return tables;
}

public List<String> getColumns(String table) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement smt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    // DatabaseMetaData dm = null;
    List<String> colList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        // dm = conn.getMetaData();
        smt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = smt.executeQuery("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM " + dbName
                + ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + table
                + "' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' ORDER BY 1");
        // rs = dm.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tName);
        while (rs.next()) {
            colList.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, smt, rs);
    }
    return colList;
}
```

it all goes to `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: If you are using the SELECT statements for the table names and the column names, then why can't you put them in the list? Where is the problem?

Comment: now so I do, but it is quite a slow process, I would like to speed up

Comment: What do you mean slow? Performance wise? Or coding?

Comment: Database have approximately 150 tables, this means the execution of 151 queries select. The entire process takes an average minute. SQuirreL SQL do this in 3-5 sec.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long even if you have a thousand tables. Something is wrong with your code. Why don't you post it so that we can tell you what's going on?

Comment: it takes ~500 Milis for each table

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post any code. What DBMS? Are you using SHOW TABLES and DESCRIBE?

Comment: It's SQL Server, all the code you have written the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that, instead of running your code in a loop for going through each table, you do it in parallel in threads. You can use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and try different thread pool sizes to see what's more efficient in terms of processing vs. RAM.

Comment: OK I will try this. Perhaps this is due to a fact that I have a database on a virtual machine, and the computer on which I am working is no speed demon.